# General idea on how to create a multiplatform application

Tags: php, android, mysql, web, multiplatform

I'm thinking about creating a multiplatform application but I'm not sure how to implement it.

For example, I have a website and I thought about making an Android app for it. It should share the database(MySQL) and have access to the files stored in cPanel.

-Is it possible?

-If it is, with JDBC connectors(maybe I'm wrong on this but I haven't really looked into those type of connections) and such should I be able to do it?

The website is php-made. If I create it on android it the app will be java obviously so the code from the website won't be shared and I would have to make new one but that's not really a problem.

Is it viable? Do I have to change the language of the website to something else more suitable?

If there is an easier way to create a website, Android App and in the future create the same app on other platforms I'd love to know it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the website hosting cpanel is better so that is wise option , however for app development I would suggest to go with Docker platform where you will be able to deploy the App and will be able to update more frequently than other platform.